# Boost::python static method returning instance of the class

Tags: c++, boost-python

Following is the my `C++ class`

```
namespace X {
  class ChildFactory: public Father {
  public:
    static ChildFactor* createChildFactory(const properties* ptr = NULLPTR);
  private :
    // no instances allowed
    ChildFactory();
    ChildFactory(const properties* ptr);
    ~ChildFactory();
  };
};
```

following is how I have defined the `Boost::Python` constructs.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(TestPy) 
{
  boost::python::class_<X::ChildFactory, boost::noncopyable>("ChildFactory")
    .def("createChildFactory", &X::ChildFactory::createChildFactory,  boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::manage_new_object>() )
    .staticmethod("createChildFactory")
  ;
}
```

But it is giving me weird compiler template error.

Error is

```
destructor could not be generated because a base class destructor is inaccessible
```

Answer (score 1):

Try exposing your class as having `no_init`:

```
class_<Foo, boost::noncopyable>("Foo", no_init);
```

Answer (score 0):

`destructor could not be generated because a base class destructor is inaccessible`

So did you solve it?

If not, what that means it is you declared your constructor function in the `private` section of the class, thats why it can not be accessed. In fact you can not instantiate that class, it can only be used as a singleton.

Move your

```
ChildFactory();
~ChildFactory();
```

to the public section and lets us know.

Answer (score 0):

`manage_new_object` might use `auto_ptr<>` which requires `delete pointer_to_ChildFactory` to work which needs access to `~ChildFactory()`.